# jQuery's find() is 'order' specific'? Why does find return zero if order changes?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm not a jQuery pro by any means and it took me quite a while to figure out how to get 'it' to work right

Here are is the piece of code:

```
$(this).parents('li:eq(0)').find('.dataPostArea').replaceWith(text); //1
$(this).parents('li:eq(0)').find('.hoverMenu').show(); //2
```

Here's the html:

```
<li class="post issuePost" data-winbook-contentType="Issue" data-winbook-issueId="null">
    <div style="display:none;" class="hoverMenu">
        <a href="#delete">
        <img class="hoverButton deleteButton" src="deleteredicon.png"/>
        </a>
        <a href="#edit">
        <img class="hoverButton editButton" src="editpencil.png"/>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="postContainer">

        <div class="avatarColumn">

            <a href="#">
            <img src="defaultavatar.jpg"/>
            </a>
            <div class="authorName">
                <a href="#">Nupul</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="postDetailsContainer">
            <div class="dataPostArea">
                <textarea class="dataForm" style="float:left; min-height:50px; min-width:330px; resize:none; margin:2px; margin-bottom:5px; overflow-x:hidden;" name="data">
                </textarea>
                <button class="addDataButton"    style="width:95px; margin:3px 2px; padding:1px 4px 1px 4px;">
                    Add Issue
                </button>
                <button class="cancelDataButton" style="width:95px; margin:3px 2px; padding:1px 4px 1px 4px;">
                    Cancel
                </button>
                <div class="clear"/>
                    <span>10 characters left</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="clear">
        </div>
</li>
```

Now if the order of 1 and 2 is as shown '.hoverMenu' is never shown. In fact the size of that jQuery object is zero! If 2 is before 1 it works fine. I'm not sure why. Any ideas?

(In case you want to know what I'm trying to accomplish: Just taking the content in an editable textarea and replacing the textarea with that content for that list item. Similar to the "add comment" functionality of stackoverflow :)

I may be performing an incorrect 'query' and corrections are more than welcome. I've not cached the `$(this).parents('li:eq(0)')` and don't think it should matter for this problem. (Should it?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your `$(this)` object is a  `<button class="addDataButton">`, correct? which you replace with txt once you post. corrrect?

what happened is that this line

```
$(this).parents('li:eq(0)').find('.dataPostArea').replaceWith(text); //1
```

will remove the button object `$(this)` , making then second line void . Thats why it showed you that it dosen't exist (didn't find any) and thats why when you switch over it works

if you want to keep the order do something this

```
listelement  = $(this).parents('li:eq(0)');
listelement.find('.dataPostArea').replaceWith(text);
listelement.find('.hoverMenu').show();
```

Comment: Well I'm *not* trying to replace the button. I'm trying to replace the entire dataPostArea div with that of the text. Yes, so the button does disappear. Now I understand. So does that mean if I cached the reference to the 'li:eq(0)' parent it would work or still fail? How would I then access the hoverMenu?

Comment: @Nupul yes, see updated code. you have to store element as using direct reference after you replace the entire post filed won''t work (as $(this) object will be removed). an obviously if it worked for you mark the answer correct :)

Comment: It worked btw :) What can I say...bad prototyping :) Thanks for the pointer!